# CSS style not working correctly with Sencha touch

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

I am building a sencha application. I want to try to use an ios switch like control. 
For that I have it in CSS: [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eTJCh/1/) (Credit to Lea Verou http://lea.verou.me)

As you can see from the jsfiddle the css works perfectly fine on the browsers.

However after adding it to my sencha application and running it on the device it is messed up. The animation is no longer playing and the **YES** side is messed up:

[image: Yes side]

What might be the problem? Are some parts of CSS not compatible with sencha apps? Why is it working normally on browsers but not on devices?

**Additional information**

I writting my CSS in a SASS file and then compile it with Compass (that's the recommended approach).

My SASS file also include some of sencha's base styles:

```
//I PASTED THE SWITCH CSS (FROM THE FIDDLE EXAMPLE) HERE

//IMPORTING THE SENCHA STYLES THAT I WILL USE
//Sencha Css
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

//Including Pictos we need to use
@include pictos-iconmask('team1');
@include pictos-iconmask('user3');
@include pictos-iconmask('settings7');
@include pictos-iconmask('shop1');

// You may remove any of the following modules that you
// do not use in order to create a smaller css file.
@include sencha-panel;
@include sencha-buttons;
@include sencha-sheet;
@include sencha-tabs;
@include sencha-toolbar;
@include sencha-toolbar-forms;
@include sencha-indexbar;
@include sencha-list;
@include sencha-layout;
@include sencha-carousel;
@include sencha-msgbox;
```

What might be the problem?

PS: I know there is a switch form control in sencha but it does not look exactly like the ios one so I had to use the above.

Thanks

Comment: "I know there is a switch form control in sencha but it does not look exactly like the ios one so I had to use the above." You could style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the third block in the css. I increased the width from 1em to 3em.

```
input[type="checkbox"].ios-switch:checked + div {
    padding-left: 2em;
    width: 3em;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

[Here is the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/Typ3C/6/)

Comment: thank you that fixed the size but the blue color for the "YES" is still not appearing and the animations not playing on the device. DO you have an idea about that? thanks a lot

Comment: It seems the problem is the ios compatibility with css gradients and transitions. Try this updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/Typ3C/5/. I modified the background-image value for the second css block. Worked in my ipod running on ios 6. Ill see if i can get the animations working tomorrow.

Comment: Updated the fiddle again which now supports the animations. Added -webkit prefix to the transition properties in the second css block. http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/Typ3C/6/

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly fine. I would like to give you a bounty for your effort in 23 hours

Comment: CAn you please edit your answer with the new fiddle in case someone is looking for it

Comment: It was a good challenge. I've updated the link to the fiddle in my answer. Bounty sounds good. :)